# Synchronizing Asynchronously made Asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, synchronization

I'm stumped

Basically, I have a http REST API to which i can make asynchronous requests to and provide a callback. I also have a web front end that will make calls to this api at arbitrary times  in arbitrary locations asynchronously.

The problem is that the api requires a 'nonce'. a number that with each subsequent request is greater than the last. generating this number in such a manner is easy. ensuring that the request arrive in the right order.. not so much.

I need a way that out side my api module I can just make the function call and provide a callback. and the module will handle ensueing that any previously made calls will finish before it makes the new request.

There is of course the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module that allows one to run asynchronous function synchronously but it requires me to know all the actions I was to fire before had. with my current system a new request could potentially be added while its in the middle of processing the first one.

in general api calls are make like so

```
// the api module
var nextNonceFunc = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var seconds = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000);
    var nonce = seconds;
    return function() {
        return nonce++;
    }
}();

var privateAPI = function(key, secret) {
    var self = this;

    var api = new API(key, secret, nextNonceFunc);

    //information about the user
    self.getInfo = function (callback) {
        api.getInfo(callback);
    };
}

// ... bla bla set up routes ect. -> enter the server request callback
// server module

// we make an api instance
var api = new privateAPI(key, secreet);

// some time later we make an api call
api.getInfo(function(err, data){
    if (err) {
        //handle error
    }
    // dosomthing with the data
})
```

I'm looking for a way to let the `privateAPI` object queue up the requests it gets.

Comment: Looks like you  need an ajax wrapper that adds all ajax requests to a queue that gets executed one at a time. However, that will have an impact on the performance of your front-end.

Comment: I'm not too worried about that. every account on the front end will have a different API key and thus a separate series of nonce. coupled with the fact that traphic will be relatively low for the application the number of api request shouldn't fire more than 10 or so api calls a minute.
but yes some sort of async wrapper that  would queue up the requests would be ideal. I'm just not sure how to structure it. (not necessarily ajax as that kind of a browser only tech.)

Comment: you would have some form of a function/module/singleton that is executed to perform ajax. The structure is very dependent on how your code uses said function and what the existing structure of your application is.

Comment: I've edited in an example of how the code is structure.

Comment: I would do research into the [Queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) method, it looks like it may do what you want.

Comment: wow, I almost can't believe I missed that, `async.queue` does indeed look like what I need, thanks. I'll be writing an answer of my own soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Kevin pointed out the existence of async.queue I was able to build the following wrapper

```
var async = require('async');


//actes as a wrapper for the passed api
module.exports = function(obj) {

    var self = this;

    var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
        var args = task.args;
        args.push(function(err, data){
            task.cb(err, data);
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback();
        })
        obj[task.func].apply(obj, args);
    }, 1);

    var keys = Object.keys(obj);

    var buildFuncWrapper = function(i) {
       self[keys[i]] = function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var task = {
                func: keys[i],
                args: args.slice(0, args.length - 1),
                cb: args.slice(args.length - 1, args.length)[0]
            };
            q.push(task, function(){
                if (global.DEBUG) console.log("[SYNC WRAPPER] finished wrapped call to: ", keys[i]);
            })
        } 
    }

    var buildPropWrapper = function(i) {
        Object.defineProperty(self, keys[i], {
            get: function () { return obj[keys[i]]},
            writable : false,
            enumerable: true
        })
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (typeof(obj[keys[i]]) === "function" ) {
            buildFuncWrapper(i);
        } else {
            buildPropWrapper(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Basicly I can pass my existing API object to it and it will forward all the calls made to it's functions through the queue, as the queue has a concurrency of 1 only one call will will process at a time.

after that it's a fairly simple matter of ensuring that only one version of this wrapped api object exists.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of client side queue would work here. Note this is extremely quick and dirty and untested and assumes jquery for my convenience:

```
var ajaxQueue = function() {
    var _queue = [];
    var _isRunning = false;

    function isRunning() {
        return _isRunning;
    }

    function run(ajaxOptions) {
        _isRunning = true;
        $.ajax({
           url : ajaxOptions.url,
           method : ajaxOptions.method,
           //etc
           success : function() {
               _isRunning = false;
               if (ajaxOptions.callback) {
                   ajaxOptions.callback();
               }  

               if (queue.length) {
                   var next = queue.shift();
                   run(next);
               }
           }
        });
    }

    return {
         add : function(ajaxOptions){
             if (isRunning()) {
                 _queue.push(ajaxOptions);
                 // return the index of the current queue item
                  return _queue.length;
              } else {
                 run(ajaxOptions);
              }
         },
         remove : function(queueIndex) {
             delete _queue[queueIndex];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that since he is using `async`, there's a built-in method that creates this kind of a queue. Good alternative though.

Comment: `delete queue[0]` is not a legal way to remove the first element of the queue - use `var next = queue.shift()` instead.